# Accessing sessionStorage and localStorage set by aura component by external Javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, aura, embedded-services

sessionStorage and localStorage are behaving odd with Locker service. It is automatically enabled and something I cannot turn off unless I resort back to API version 39. The locker sevice automatically "wraps" (key, value) in a wrapper, which makes it impossible to get value by key using the localStorage.getItem (key) method.

In the picture below you can see that my value was set with namespace c and key 'sfdc-order-portal-token'. The result is Key: LSSIndex:LOCAL{"namespace":"c"} Value: {"page":3} where 3 has become a new key with the value.

[image]

How can I have an external website read these key-value pairs that I am storing in local storage?

Comment: Salesforce is restricting access to these values for security reasons. Perhaps you need to consider using an alternative approach.

Comment: Should I be using lwc instead? @PhilW

Comment: The Locker Service or the Lightning Web Security layer is always used. You cannot turn off security. Cross-namespace limitations are removed in LWS at least for LWCs. You should check LWS, but I expect security requirements will still block this approach. Try an alternative way to pass info.